# Building a 3d sound

Tags: winapi, audio

I am trying to improve my own WaveApi library, that actually plays different sounds simultaneously using mixed buffers of stereo 44100 sine waves.

What I would like, now that I control volume and hertz on 2 channels, is to simulate a sound heard far away. Easily done by reducing the stereo levels of that sound.

But, for a sound located behind the observer, I have no solution for making the difference with front sounds.

Is there a way to play with hertz or levels to hear something far in front or in back?

Comment: Mixing audio by hand is very difficult, especially the more complex the audio is. You really should use a pre-existing audio library/API that handles this stuff for you. That being said, since you are asking to produce spatial audio with just 2 channels, you will likely have to first produce audio for more channels (ie, surround sound typically uses 6 or 8 channels, placed around the observer), and then you can adjust the samples and levels on the individual channels as needed, and then finally mix the channels together as needed to produce 2 channels...

Comment: ... But, the resulting sound is not going to seem to be behind the observer, since it is not actually playing behind the observer. That is what the extra channels are meant for, so they can be physically positioned around the observer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using static spatial audio objects, dynamic spatial audio objects, and spatial audio objects that use Microsoft's Head Relative Transfer Function (HRTF) to implement spatial sound.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Render Spatial Sound Using Spatial Audio Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/render-spatial-sound-using-spatial-audio-objects)

And here is an sample you could refer to: [Microsoft Spatial Sound samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/render-spatial-sound-using-spatial-audio-objects)

Comment: Thank you very much... That doesnt answer to my question that is how to adress individual channels within a wave structure but near as we must use rendering audioobjects...

Comment: @blueperfect If a proposed answer doesn't answer your question then don't accept it.